# Iterar objeto Json en PHP

Tags: php, json, api

Estoy haciendo una llamada a una API creada por mi, la cual me devuelve un listado de usuarios en el siguiente formato:

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "data": {
        "usuarios": [
            {
                "_id": "6195699249d6996a7733e49b",
                "apellido": "perez",
                "email": "a@a.com",
                "password": "aaaaaa",
                "nombre": "Juan"
            },
    ...
    }
```

Lo que quiero es iterar sobre "data", accediendo a "usuarios", y mostrarlos todos en un HTML.
Estoy probando el siguiente código pero no consigo que funcione y no se dónde pueda estar el fallo:

```
<?php
    $res = file_get_contents("http://localhost:3000/");
    $data = json_decode($res);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><?php 
        foreach ($data->data->usuarios as $usuario){
            echo $usuario;
        }
    ?></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

El error es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Tu error es que andas imprimiendo el Array Completo como variable.

Si deseas imprimir el valor completo es :

```
print_r($usuario);
```

Ahora si es un valor debes mandar uno por uno:

Ejemplo:

```
echo $usuario->apellido;

echo $usuario->password;
```

Comment: Dios mio que error mas estúpido, muchas gracias!!